# asp.NET Razor new Page error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Im pretty new to Razor and asp.NET so please dont judge me if my question might seem somehow stupid.

I created a razor project in VS2013 and now I created a new cshtml page.
I only added some small things like labels and input fields there. I then wanted to link the template Index page to my own page with a simple:

```
<a href="~/Views/Acquisition/AC_Create.cshtml" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Login &raquo;</a>
```

When I then try to click on the link in the browser I get the error that the resource could not be found.

If I open the page in the "Page Inspector" the error display is the same with the additional information:

```
    <!--[HttpException]: A public action method &#39;User&#39; was not found on controller &#39;VitaminB.Controllers.UserController&#39;.
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HandleUnknownAction(String actionName)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   bei System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   bei System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   bei System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)-->
```

Sorry for the bad formating, trying my best =/

Comment: Sorry the links are wrong since I tried something else I just saw again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in fact, when you type a `URL` in the url bar (same as your link) , you have to point the `controller`, not the `view`. Then, once reached, Controller can `call a view`. So you always have to point a `controller` that maybe just shiw you a `view`. `View` can only be pointed from a `controller`.

Link:

```
<a href="/somecontroller/someaction/123">link text</a>
```

or better:

```
@Html.ActionLink("link text", "someaction", "somecontroller", new { id = "123" }, null)
```

In the somecontroller controller:

```
public ActionResult someaction(int id)
{
 // process
 return View('viewname'); // viewname.cshtml must be present in /View/somecontroller/
}
```

NB: if the `view` is the same name ad the `controller` (somecontroller  is the name of the `controller` and of the `view`), you can just

```
return View();
```

Comment: @VIP please consider accepting a answer if an answer solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you create a link in MVC: Try using @Html.ActionLink(...)

(you should read some "getting started with MVC" type tutorials: you need to learn about routing, you never link to a .cshtml file directly)

Comment: Thanks, I will do that :)
Looking at this one now: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-controller